# What's difference between "$!" and "$?" in bash shell special parameters?

Tags: bash, shell

I know `$?` returns the last status code and also `$!`.

What is the exact difference of usage between the two.

Thanks

#### Edit : Dear Downvoters, I haven't removed this question since i want it to be indexed on Google, it's not easy to find documentation when searching on Google about this issue.

#### Sincerely

Comment: See: [Bash Reference Manual, 3.4.2 Special Parameters](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC28)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.

`$!` is the process identifier of the most recent background command and
`$?` is like you said, the most recent foreground pipeline exit status.

Reference point : http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC28

Comment: Woops foreground is fine, sorry for the confusion.

I added the word -> pipeline is to be more specific. Like when you run a command that executes a chain of script e.g. "script_1 | script_2 | script_3", when it is done, the return code is not for the entire command but is only for the most recent executed script.

Comment: Thanks, that really clarified the difference between "foreground pipeline" and "foreground".